# How can I set associations between models in Cake PHP 3.5?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, orm

I have a db structure like this in MySql. And I use Cake PHP 3.5.
[image: My schema in MySql Workbranch]

I wolud like to add to table1 a belongsToMany connection to table4. And add its inverse to table4 too.

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Table4', /*What goes here*/);
```

And what is for table4?

Can I make this Join with a finder in the belongsToMany?

Thanks!

Comment: CakePHPs built-in many-to-many association doesn't support spanning over multiple join tables. I'd suggest that you elaborate on the actual problem that you are trying to solve with that schema, then maybe someone can suggest a way to implement a solution using existing CakePHP functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ndm said in comments Cake does not suport what you want to do, just for a reason, this is not a many to many relation, please create you database by migrations, first of all https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/migrations.html after that (bake migration, execute migration) your database will exist, the you can run a bake for create models, then you will realize that you can build a query like

```
$this->table1->table2->table3->table4->find()->where([conditions]);
```

or another like

```
$this->table1->find()->contain(['table2' => ['table3' => ['table4' => 'conditions' => ['RealConditions']]]])->first();
```

If you don't want to learn all of this you can go throught the paintfull path. Or just read about it first https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations